# Set value if entered value is more than a {number}

Tags: jquery, parseint

I have a block, width and height of which I want user to set by entering a value in the input.

I also want the value of inputs not to be more than certain number. Seems like I can't get `parseInt` to work..

```js
if (parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10) > 113) {
  $("#stwidth").val("113");
}

if (parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10) > 62) {
 $("#stheight").val("62");
  
}

$("#stwidth, #stheight").keyup(function () {
  $('.preview').css({width: $("#stwidth").val() + "mm", height: $("#stheight").val() + "mm"});
});
```

```css
.preview {
    width: 55mm;
    height: 19mm;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #3e6eb0;
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stwidth" id="stwidth" value="55" maxlength="3"> x 
<input type="text" name="stheight" id="stheight"  value="19" maxlength="2"> 

<div class="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, what are you trying to achieve? You use `#stwidth` in the second if statement instead of `#stheight`. So `parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10) > 62` should be `parseInt($("#stheight").val(), 10) > 62` I believe.

Comment: Thanks. it's just a typo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing was using Jquery keyup event handler on document onload for those user inputs. Here I'm giving a working solution, it'll not allow the width to be greater than 113 and height to be greater than 62:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .preview {
            width: 55mm;
            height: 19mm;
            background: #fff;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 2px solid #3e6eb0;
            margin: 50px 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#stwidth").keyup(function() {
                if (parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10) > 113) {
                    $("#stwidth").val("113");
                }
            });

            $("#stheight").keyup(function() {
                if (parseInt($("#stheight").val(), 10) > 62) {
                    $("#stheight").val("62");

                }
            });

            $("#stwidth, #stheight").keyup(function() {
                $('.preview').css({
                    width: $("#stwidth").val() + "mm",
                    height: $("#stheight").val() + "mm"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<input type="text" name="stwidth" id="stwidth" value="55" maxlength="3"> x
<input type="text" name="stheight" id="stheight" value="19" maxlength="2">

<div class="preview"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: What a shame... 

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#stwidth, #stheight").keyup(function () {
  if (parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10) > 113) {
    $("#stwidth").val("113");
  }
  if (parseInt($("#stheight").val(), 10) > 62) {
 $("#stheight").val("62");
  }
  $('.preview').css({width: $("#stwidth").val() + "mm", height: $("#stheight").val() + "mm"});
});
```

```css
.preview {
    width: 55mm;
    height: 19mm;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #3e6eb0;
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stwidth" id="stwidth" value="55" maxlength="3"> x 
<input type="text" name="stheight" id="stheight"  value="19" maxlength="2"> 

<div class="preview"></div>
```

The problem was with your if conditions. It was out of the keyup function, so that it will only render one time. But now it will render every time when the user press the key

Comment: Nice. Thanks to you too.

Comment: @AzamatSafarov Welcome. If you like this post please accept this as best answer.  :)